# VHDL - Trying to subtract from a natural and bit_vector

Tags: vhdl

Im trying to subtract from a natural in vhdl, but i can`t understand how to do it, any one have an ideia on what i can change in my code?
My problem is, i cant figure out what i can change to make the cnt go down 1 by 1 untill gets to zero.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 

entity dsf_monostable is
  port (
    aclear  : in  bit;
    data    : in  natural range 0 to 255;
    trigger : in  bit;
    clk     : in  bit;
    q       : out bit
  );
end dsf_monostable;

architecture monostable_arc of dsf_monostable is
  signal cnt : natural range 0 to 255 := 0;
begin
  process (aclear, trigger, cnt)
  begin

    if (aclear = '1') then 
      cnt <= 0;  

    elsif (trigger = '1' and cnt = 0) then
      cnt <= data;
    end if;
  end process;

  process (clk, cnt)
  begin
    if ((clk'event and clk = '1') and cnt /= 0) then
      cnt <= cnt - 1;
    end if;
  end process;

  q <= '0' when (cnt=0 or aclear='1') 
           else '1';
end monostable_arc;
```

And for bit_vector

```
architecture timer_arc of dsf_timer is
  signal cnt : bit_vector (7 downto 0);

begin
process (clk)
  begin
    if ((clk'event and clk = '1') and (cnt > "00000000")) then
    cnt <= cnt - "00000001"
     end if;
  end process;
```

I expect that cnt will decrement 1 when the rising_clk happen

Comment: You dont clearly state what the problem is. You also dont show a complete example as libraries are missing. Arithmetic with bit_vector is only possible with standard in VHDL 2008  with numeric_bit_unsigned package. You first example does nothing as cnt is initialised to 0, so no decrementing to done as you never decrement when cnt is 0. If you did try and decrement, you would get an out of bounds exception.

Comment: A [mcve] would include a clear problem statement. There is IEEE package numeric_bit which can be used with type bit_vector instead of package numeric_std since 1990. For uses without a -2008 compliant tool chain you `use ieee.numeric_bit.all;` and declare `cnt` as type `unsigned` (ieee.numeric_bit.unsigned).